# Hillshade tool in ArcMap returning terraced, pixelated image

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, hillshade

I am applying Hillshade tool (ArcMap 10.1) to SRTM in Caucasus Mountains (border between Russia and Georgia). It gives me weird image with 'terraces' (see attachment). I reprojected SRTM from WGS-1984 to UTM 37 zone using cubic convolution, but it didn't help. Also, I tried to apply Z-factor 0.00001171 for 40 degr. like it says here : http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2007/06/12/setting-the-z-factor-parameter-correctly/, but it says:

> The numeric value is outside of the valid range.

How do I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is a function of the resolution of the source DEM. You could try to run a filter on the hill shade to smooth it out.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Ryan! It looks like I shouldn't have resampled my SRTM from 90 to 30 meters.

Comment: This striping effect is commonly see when projecting or resampling floating point rasters using a nearest neighbor resampling method. I would recheck you workflow to see where this resampling method may have been applied. It is the default resampling method in ArcGIS but should never be applied to a floating point raster.